# storing data after reading a file in a Qvector

Tags: c++, qt5

I have a weird problem not sure why:

I made a program that checks if the user entered a valid name " which checks qvector first " if it find it then it says that it was found, the problem is since the qvector was a little big i made a txt file and put the names in there line by line like this:

name1
name2
name3
.
.
.
.

I used this function to read it line by line using qfile

```
for (int i=0; !names->atEnd(); i++){
    q_names[i]=names->readLine();
    }
```

q_names is a qvector of QString

I checked using qline edit to display if it was copied or not and it was!! " I showed it using settext(q_names[3]) for example and it works like a charm.

now when I tried to let the user enter a string and checks if it was in  the vector or not , I used this:

```
for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
    if(lineedit_names->text()==S_names[i]){
..}
```

but it doesn't work

the above is just an example hopefully it'll clear the problem, and here's some pics to know what I was talking about:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2wd7iph&s=8

http://oi61.tinypic.com/2wd7iph.jpg

when it finds it " matches " it sets the line edits down there to true and enable it

what is strange is when I enter the last value that was in the text file it enables it like there's no problem " which mean it found that value "

I'm guessing it's because of the new line ?

Comment: For anyone having the same problem I managed to solve it using qtextstream , if you use qfile function's " read.line() " it'll count the \n , but if you used the qtextstream it won't count it.

Comment: Please don't use external image hosting services for question images. Such images often get deleted and make questions less useful. Stack Overflow comes with wonderfully simple to use image insertion, use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're reading directly through the QFile then you are using `QIODevice::readLine`. The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readLine) for that states that it leaves the newline character in place. In that case they will be included in the comparison and you will need to remove them for the comparison you want.

If instead you use a `QTextStream` to read the file as shown in the [`QFile` documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfile.html#using-streams-to-read-files) then any newline (and carriage return if on windows) characters will be automatically trimmed.

Comment: Thanks , I actually fixed it about an hour ago ^^ and I used your exact solution , hopefully anyone with the same problem will find this post to fix it ^^